# how to solve Pyqt5 create web browser when load html crash

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I created a web browser by PyQt5 ,if I load url="http://www.google.com" have nothing issues,but if I load url = "http://192.168.0.106/get.html" ,run the code, the widgets crash.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
import sys  

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    """docstring for MainWindow"""
    def __init__(self, *arg,**kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*arg,**kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle("Load huobi exchange bar")

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://192.168.0.106/get.html"))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

bellow is the content of  get.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>huobi exchange bar</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
    <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
    <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://cn.tradingview.com/crypto-screener/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">sample</span></a>TradingView</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-screener.js" async>
    {
    "width": 1100,
    "height": 512,
    "defaultColumn": "overview",
    "defaultScreen": "general",
    "market": "crypto",
    "showToolbar": true,
    "colorTheme": "dark",
    "locale": "zh_CN"
  }
    </script>
  </div>
  <!-- TradingView Widget END -->
</body>
</html>
```

my question is :how to solve the window crash when load about async js?

Comment: Do you have a server that loads the HTML?

Comment: yes,I do.I have a server in local host.  I can open directly  the get.html in chrome .

Comment: Then you must indicate how you run your host, you must give more information ....

Comment: And as I indicated in my answer: it is recommended that you run your code in the CMD/console since you will be able to obtain more information about the error.

Comment: I mean that if the content of html  don't include the javascript  like this :"src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-screener.js" async  " ,the widget display normally .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand why the application is broken because even if the url did not exist this should show you the error page so if you want more details of the error you should run the code in the console/CMD.

On the other hand you do not indicate that any server executes the HTML, in addition it is not necessary to use the "http://192.168.0.106" host, just load it as a local file:

```
├── get.html
└── main.py
```

```py
import os
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    """docstring for MainWindow"""

    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*arg, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle("Load huobi exchange bar")

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()

        current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "get.html")
        url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)
        self.browser.setUrl(url)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help.  I copy your code in my pc,excute it ,but the widget only display about 8 seconds and then auto closed .

Comment: @Baren Where do you run it? In the console/CMD or in some IDE? what is your OS?

Comment: @Baren Please just answer me in a thread, what version of PyQt5 do you use? In addition to the previous questions.

Comment: I run it in both IDE(sublime) and CMD,my OS is win10

Comment: @Baren Do you get an error message in the case of CMD? What version of python and pyqt5 do you use?

Comment: PYQT_VERSION = 331008  PYQT_VERSION_STR = 5.13.0

Comment: @Baren How have you installed pyqt5 and pyqtwebengine? previous question: Do you get an error message in the case of CMD?

Comment: @Baren mmm, it seems strange to me since the code you provide is correct and I do not see the reason that chashed, perhaps it is a pyqtwebengine bug for windows since in Linux it works correctly. Try updating pyqt5 and pyqtwebengine: `pip install -U pyqt5 pyqtwebengine`

Comment: after upgrade to the latest version of pyqt5 pyqtwebengine ,it works!  thank you very much !